# Unable to cast the type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.Object' in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have the following code:

```
public static IQueryable<T> ApplyOrdering<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, IQueryObject queryObject, Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<T, Object>>> columnsMap)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(queryObject.SortBy) || !columnsMap.ContainsKey(queryObject.SortBy))
            return query;

        if (queryObject.IsSortAscending)
            return query.OrderBy(columnsMap[queryObject.SortBy]);
        else
            return query.OrderByDescending(columnsMap[queryObject.SortBy]);
    }
```

But I get the following error if object in the dictionary is a date:

> Unable to cast the type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

This the code for the columnsMap that I pass through to call the above extension method:

```
  var columnsMap = new Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<Post, Object>>>
  {
            ["createdDate"] = p => p.CreatedDate
  };

  query = query.ApplyOrdering(queryObject, columnsMap);
```

How can I fix?

Comment: What line throws that exception?

Comment: The problem is with mapping rather ordering it seems

Comment: @abatishchev what is the problem with the mapping please see my updated code?

Comment: Now your order by looks like this: `ctx.SomeTable.OrderBy(x => (object) x.CreatedDate)`. EF doesn't like this, so you need to rewrite your expression and remove that object cast.

Comment: @Evk how would i rewrite the expression. It was suppose to be generic so that It could be used with any type.

Comment: if you are still looking for the correct solution. have a look at my answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52030539/7369310

Comment: it probably cause of `Expression<>`, you should be using `Func<>`

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is in `Expression<Func<T, Object>>> columnsMap`

[`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) isn't a class, is a struct so if your signature wait for an Object and you pass a primitive type, it throws the exception.

However, I don't know how to fix it, at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

it probably cause of `Expression<>`, you should be using `Func<>`. have a look at my answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52030539/7369310